# Trying to simplify a stubborn expression in SymPy - complex exponential / trigonometric space vector equation

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to simplify

```
cos(phi) + cos(phi - 2*pi/3)*e^(I*2*pi/3) + cos(phi - 4*pi/3)*e^(I*4*pi/3)
```

which I know reduces down to 1.5e^(I*phi)

I cannot get SymPy to recognize this. I have tried `simplify`, `trigsimp`, `expand`, etc. But nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sympy as sp
from sympy import I 
sp.init_printing()
phi = sp.symbols('\phi', real = True)

vec = sp.cos(phi) + sp.cos(phi - 2*sp.pi/3)*sp.exp(I*2*sp.pi/3) + sp.cos(phi - 4*sp.pi/3)*sp.exp(I*4*sp.pi/3)

vec.simplify()
vec.rewrite(sp.exp).simplify()
vec.rewrite(sp.exp).expand().simplify()
```

None of these produce the expected result.
I can confirm my result manually, by substituting values in for `phi` like this:

```
sp.simplify(vec.rewrite(sp.exp).simplify() - 3/2*sp.exp(I*phi)).evalf(subs={phi:3})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious but you can get there like this:

```
In [40]: phi = symbols('phi', real=True)

In [41]: e = cos(phi) + cos(phi - 2*pi/3)*E**(I*2*pi/3) + cos(phi - 4*pi/3)*E**(I*4*pi/3)

In [42]: e
Out[42]: 
   -2⋅ⅈ⋅π                         2⋅ⅈ⋅π           
   ───────                        ─────           
      3       ⎛    π⎞               3      ⎛    π⎞
- ℯ       ⋅sin⎜φ + ─⎟ + cos(φ) - ℯ     ⋅cos⎜φ + ─⎟
              ⎝    6⎠                      ⎝    3⎠

In [43]: e.rewrite(exp).expand().rewrite(sin).expand().rewrite(exp)
Out[43]: 
   ⅈ⋅φ
3⋅ℯ   
──────
  2
```

Comment: Nice! Call that the `extxe` transformation (exp/expand/trig/expand/exp rewrite).

Comment: Nice. Is there some lesson to take away from this on why it is necessary to transform so many times between `exp` and `sin`?

Comment: If you follow through the steps one by one you can sort of see why each is needed. The first rewrite+expand combines the exponential and trig. Often that's all that's needed but you get `I*exp(-5*I*pi/6)` which doesn't properly cancel with `exp(I*pi/3)` (they add to one) so the second rewrite makes that happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an example in which doing computation by hands might be faster then exploring how to do it with SymPy.

Anyway, this is how I achieve that:

```
vec.rewrite(exp).simplify().subs(
    root(-1, 6),
    root(-1, 6).rewrite(exp)
).expand().subs(
    I * exp(-5 * I * pi / 6),
    (I * exp(-5 * I * pi / 6)).simplify().rewrite(exp)
).simplify().expand()

# out: 3*exp(I*\phi)/2
```